# PhoneGap error when trying to record audio

Tags: cordova

I am new to Phonegap and I am trying to record a audio using it. I followed the code given by PhoneGap API but it is throwing the following exception in the console:

```
04-19 08:59:55.934: E/Web Console(4197): TypeError: Result of expression
'navigator.device' [undefined] is not an object. 
at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:31
code at line 31 is navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit: 2});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is bug in **PhoneGap 1.5**. You should use **PhoneGap 1.6.1**.

You can copy the code from PhoneGap API and change it according to your requirements.